# Does SetWindowDisplayAffinity apply to ComboBox drop-down lists?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, winapi

I've been messing about with my sandbox app, testing features before submitting them to the main project. One of these features is the ability to use SetWindowDisplayAffinity to hide the program's UI from capturing programs. It works perfectly when I try to use the screen-capture function in Windows or a screen-recording application like OBS Studio, but the issue arises when I use a ComboBox control to drop-down a list of selectable items.

It appears that SetWindowDisplayAffinity has no effect on the menu that shows. I tried both the Monitor Display Affinity option and the newer ExcludeFromCapture mode, but both had the same outcome. I'm not sure if the control (or UI) created when accessing the ComboBox list has its own handle that isn't affected, or if SetWindowDisplayAffinity just ignores ComboBoxes.

I've included two examples that I hope help to clarify the situation. The red text and red box are what I see, whereas the yellow text and yellow box are what the screen-capture utilities see. The Display Affinity is indicated by the light blue text.

[SetWindowDisplayAffinity is disabled. When using screen-capture software, all UI components become visible.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rd9Ib.png) &
[SetWindowDisplayAffinity is enabled and configured. All UI components should be visible exclusively to the user and not the screen-capture program. The ComboBox list appears to ignore this request.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPgnK.png)

The code I'm using is messy (since it's solely for testing), but I've chosen to rework it for easier reading. You can view the code used in my test project below:

This is the DLL Import request that I use. It does not appear to be creating any issues and appears to be a valid import request. No Win32 errors are generated:

```cs
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Winapi)]
public static extern uint SetWindowDisplayAffinity(IntPtr Handle, DisplayAffinity Affinity);

public enum DisplayAffinity : uint
{
    None = 0x0,
    Monitor = 0x1,
    ExcludeFromCapture = 0x11
}
```

This is how I used the API call. The first code block is the "official way" I generally use, whereas the second and third code blocks are "hacky attempts" I've made:

```cs
void HideFromCapture()
{
    // <Handle> being the Form's main window handle. In this case, <MainForm.Handle>.
    SetWindowDisplayAffinity(Handle, DisplayAffinity.ExcludeFromCapture);
    // I would call <HideFromCapture()> once all UI components are loaded.
}
```

```cs
void HideFromCaptureFixOne()
{
    // Now I'm attempting to apply the call to both the Form and the ComboBox directly.
    SetWindowDisplayAffinity(Handle, DisplayAffinity.ExcludeFromCapture);
    SetWindowDisplayAffinity(MyComboBox.Handle, DisplayAffinity.ExcludeFromCapture);
    // As expected, this had no effect.
}
```

```cs
void HideFromCaptureOrLoseAllHope()
{
    // I've determined that brute-forcing will undoubtedly cure everything wrong.
    foreach(Control Target in Controls)
    {
        try
        {
            // I'm quite sure this is NOT how you should use this function. Oh well...
            SetWindowDisplayAffinity(Target.Handle, DisplayAffinity.ExcludeFromCapture);
        }
        catch
        {
            // Ignorance is bliss.
            continue;
        }
    }

    /*
     * Now I want to reinstate that I am calling these functions when running my
     * program. It does work on the Form but not the ComboBox. I've even tried
     * the Control loop method above and I even tried calling this function in a loop.
     * It didn't work either. It did make the program chomp on memory however. No surprise.
    */
}
```

So now I'm stuck. I was hesitant to pose a question here since I felt like I was answering my own questions while attempting to "solve the issue," but it keeps bothering me while testing my projects. I don't enjoy developing code that I believe does not operate properly, resulting in this feature standing out like a sore thumb and not making it into the official project build. I've determined that it wouldn't hurt to seek for some assistance with this issue, and if I can't fix it, I'll just make due with what I have. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The documentation states that it only works on top level windows.  I wonder if the combobox is creating a new 'top-level' window, and you somehow need to capture the hWnd of that, to call the API when it's being displayed?

Comment: @Neil That might be the case here. I'll see if I can implement GetTopWindow() and any other relevant functions and see if they'll have any sort of difference. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @NerdSwim Please do not add answers to the *question* part of the question.

Comment: @GSerg Noticed the revision roll-back. Gotcha. Alright to edit my posted answer with the one placed on the question?

Comment: @NerdSwim Yes please.

Comment: For Combobox specifically, the dropdown is a separate top-level window (this allows it to popup outside its parent). You could use `GetComboboxInfo` function or `CB_GETCOMBOBOXINFO` message to get the HWND handle of the popup https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getcomboboxinfo